# Displaying the same images in different lists with a view flipper

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-image, viewflipper, android-adapterview

I have viewflipper which contains 3 childs, one `GridView` and two custom `ListView`, every view has different adapter , and every adapter has a image loader with Universal Image Loader library.

The items are the same for all adapters, my goal is to show content in different way (grid , list , and big list), but in this way every image loads 3 times. Is there any way to load images once and show them to their childs?

[image]

Comment: You may use Glide or Picasso libraries for  image cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need an object common to the three views, which manages image loading and holds memory. You have it: it's the `Adapter`. Use a single one and just switch layouts.

For instance, you could define this method inside the adapter:

```
int layoutResId;
public void changeLayout(int layoutResId) {
    this.layoutResId = layoutResId;
    notifyDataSetChanged(); //force the adapter to call getView() again
}
```

Then in your `getView()` method you just inflate the layout defined by `layoutResId`.

Comment: it is good idea ,I have 2 listview which are the same but the gridview adapter are very different , what about that?

Comment: It might require some work, but this is the natural solution to your issue. If you don't want to, note that some libraries (don't know about UIL) will cache the bitmaps so that they don't get loaded twice. Search around about caching in UIL (or other similar libraries).

Comment: I already enabled the caching , but since image loader codes runs all in same time for first time  , it's loading the images very slow , after caching every thing goes fine , maybe I have to make one adapter after all

Comment: I understand. I believe so :-)

Answer (score 0):

Well the thing that you seem to be asking is if you can pass the images along to the other adapters.  It would be something like if image is not empty them use it in the other views, if not then use the image loader.

```
public class Constants {
    public static Constants INSTANCE = new Constants();
    public Constants() {
    }

    public Uri IMAGE_PATH = Uri.EMPTY;
    public File IMAGE_FILE = null;
    public Bitmap IMAGE = null;
}
```

Presumably you would choose only one of these kinds to save from your view. And then check them to see if constants possesses an image for you to display.